# Как ускорить загрузку страницы, если на ней много аудио файлов на 250 мб?

Tags: javascript, аудио, оптимизация-сайтов

Я новичок в сайтостроительстве и недавно таки выложил свой первый сайт..Но сразу возникла проблема с прогрузкой аудио. На самой странице аудио материала на 250 МБ, что существенно замедляет загрузку(. Помогите с оптимизацией плз! http://borovinsky.me/project_music.php?project_id=2#project

Comment: не загружать аудио сразу же, а только при необходимости

Comment: да у вас картинок на 10 мегабайт оО

Comment: огромные картинки загружаете для маленьких превью альбома у трека, не нужно так. Если картинка будет маленькой на сайте, делайте ее маленькой на сервере

Comment: спасибо уважаемые я постараюсь это исправить!